# Can I detect vim is in debugger mode through --remote-expr?

Tags: clientserver

In general I can programmatically detect the active mode on a vim instance using

```
$ vim --remote-expr 'mode(1)'
```

but when vim is in debugger mode (i.e., it has hit a breakpoint placed via `:breakadd`), it seems to just return `c` (Command-line mode) instead of identifying the mode as a debug prompt. Is there some other way I can detect debug prompt?

Context: For software that instruments vim like https://github.com/google/vroom, it would be useful to be able to handle debug mode specially instead of assuming vim is "stuck".